# How do you draw the text bubbles for telepathic communication in comics?

Tags: comics

How do you draw the text bubbles for telepathic communication in comics? I don't recall having ever seen text bubbles for telepathic speech between 2 or more characters. I am especially interested to see how this is done when there's 3 or more characters, because I can't really think of a good way. Could you show some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *UnOrdinary*, speech bubbles are always colored according to the character (usually matching their hair). When they think, the thought bubbles (stylized with a thick, sunburst outline as is common in manga) are colored the same way. And, finally, when characters are shown communicating via telepathy, those same colored thought bubbles are used and the foreheads of the characters who are involved in the communication light up, which distinguishes regular thought from telepathy (it's unclear if that is an effect added for the audience or light is actually produced). Here's an example:

[image: blue thought bubble over girl's head: "can you hear me?". Girl says "…!!!" in her purple speech bubble]
[Episode 255](https://www.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/unordinary/episode-255/viewer?title_no=679&episode_no=268)

This isn't the only way. There are some other attribution techniques that I've seen used for regular speech from an off panel character that would also work for telepathy:

- Writing the name or initial of the character who's speaking near the bubble.
- Drawing the character's head under (sometimes on) the bubble to indicate it belongs to them. The head is usually drawn in chibi style or another simplified style. This also allows the character to show a few facial expressions without having to switch back to them completely.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a zig-zag (lightning bolt) line between puffy, cloud-shaped text bubbles. Drawing characters with eyes closed would add to the effect.